# Java autoboxing and ternary operator madness

Tags: java, operator-keyword, autoboxing, ternary

Just spent a frustrating couple of hours debugging this code:

```
    LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> rsrqs = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();
    Integer boxedPci = 52;
    Integer boxedRsrq = boxedPci != null ? rsrqs.get(boxedPci.toString()) : -1;
```

The above produces a NullPointerException. The below code doesn't:

```
    LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> rsrqs = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();
    Integer boxedPci = 52;
    Integer boxedRsrq = boxedPci != null ? rsrqs.get(boxedPci.toString()) : Integer.valueOf(-1);
```

The only difference is wrapping the -1 with Integer.valueOf(). I'm sure I'm going to smack my forehead once somebody explains why this code behaves the way it does.. but can someone explain to me why this code behaves the way it does :)?

--
Edit

On second thought, I suspect that the NPE is coming from the rsrqs.get() returning null, which I think java is attempting to unbox into an int, before boxing back to an Integer. The Integer.valueOf() forces Java to do the unbox-box step. Moral of the story; don't just ignore those boxing warnings in Eclipse ;)

Comment: none is giving me a NPE, please check the code

Comment: @Chechus It gives to me.

Comment: Ternary operator is weird for sure. Have you also noticed how in Java for an if or while loop the condition mandates wrapping in parentheses. Yet on condition of ternary it's not required. I got tripped up on a similar issue today - down to assumption autoboxing would occur. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69552017/why-does-this-code-give-a-null-pointer-exception-i-thought-character-class-coul

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Ternary expressions, like any expression, have a type that is determined by the compiler. If the two sides of the ternary expression have what looks like different types, then the compiler will try and find a common base type using the least ambiguous of the two options. In your case, the `-1` is least ambiguous, and so the type of the ternary expression is `int`. Sadly, the compiler doesn't use type inference based on the receiving variable.

The expression `rsrqs.get(boxedPci.toString())` is then evaluated and forced into type `int` to match the ternary expression, but because it's `null` it throws the NPE.

By boxing the `-1`, the value of the ternary expression is `Integer`, and so you're null-safe.

Comment: Well after a test, with java 1.8 the result es different (returns a null, no NPE). Ideas?

Comment: @Chechus: Java8's type inference is a lot better. That's a side effect of the lambda expression support. My guess is that the type of the ternary expression is now being influenced by the type of the receiver (i.e. it's being assigned to an `Integer`, so let's make the type of the expression `Integer` and stop trying to unbox the null)

Comment: @skaffman: it seems to be a side-effect of implementing the better type inference, but by reading the specification I got the feeling, you should not rely on it as “numeric conditional expressions” are explicitly stated to be no “poly expressions”, read, not affected by the target type.

Comment: actually, this might be a javac bug; and the spec is probably bad too. see the very last example in http://stackoverflow.com/a/33182091

Answer (score 12):

The explanation can be concluded from the information in [java language specification: 15.25. Conditional Operator ? :](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25).

From the table there, you get the information, that, if the second operand (`rsrqs.get(boxedPci.toString())`) is of type `Integer` and the third operand is of type `int`, the result will be of type `int`.

That however means, that

```
Integer boxedRsrq = boxedPci != null ? rsrqs.get(boxedPci.toString()) : -1;
```

is semantically the same as

```
Integer boxedRsrq = boxedPci != null ? ((int)rsrqs.get(boxedPci.toString())) : -1;
```

But that means you get a `NullPointerException`, if you get `null` from the map, which obviously happens.

If you cast the third operand to `Integer`, the second operand will never be cast to `int` and no NPE happens.

Answer (score 4):

Well, [`Integer.valueOf(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29) returns an `Integer` and -1 is a primitive `int`.  The first example is forced to unbox because one term is a primitive. You could also have used

```
Integer boxedRsrq = boxedPci != null ? 
    rsrqs.get(boxedPci.toString()) : (Integer) -1;
```

which would have boxed the -1.

Answer (score 3):

```
1
```

is an int, not an Integer. So, Java is going to un-box your Integer to int, which causes the NullPointerException. When you auto-unbox a null Integer, it results in a NullPointerException. ( [reference here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html) )

But when you use

```
 Integer.valueOf(-1)
```

it doesn't need to auto-unbox it, which leads to no exceptions.