# Wrappers and Auto-boxing

Tags: java, wrapper, autoboxing

There is the following code:

```
Integer time = 12;
Double lateTime = 12.30;
Boolean late = false;
Double result = late ? lateTime : time;  //Why here can I assign an Integer to a Double?
System.out.println(result);
```

It prints:

> 12.0

This one doesn't compile. Why?

```
Integer time = 12;
Double lateTime = 12.30;
Double result = time;      //Integer cannot be converted to Double
System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: Double result = time+1.0; would also compile

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java autoboxing and ternary operator madness](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25417438/java-autoboxing-and-ternary-operator-madness)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The differences are due to the ternary operator behaviour in Java.

---

**The ternary conditional case:**

In the expression `late ? lateTime : time`, Java will auto-unbox exactly one of the arguments (according to the value of `late`) to its respective primitive type. (You can observe this by setting `time` to `null` and `late` to `true`: a `NullPointerException` is *not* thrown. The same applies when setting `lastTime` to `null` and `late` to `false`.)

If the value of the expression will be `time`, then this is *widened* to a `double`.

In either case, the resulting `double` is auto-boxed to a `Double` in assigning it to `result`.

---

**The simple assignment case:**

In writing `Double result = time;`, Java disallows this as it expects you to be more explicit.

---

<sup>Personally I find the mechanism of the Java ternary conditional operator with respect to the boxed primitive types to be one of the most pernicious parts of the language.</sup>

Comment: Ok, but in the first exemple 'result' is always a Double or is casted into an Integer?

Comment: @Eran: I've been more explicit about the precise mechanism, and added the NPE sting.

Comment: Double result = time+1.0; would also compile. In fact so would + 0.0; And +1 just for the use of the word pernicious.

Comment: @Eran: Yes I was inaccurate. I've also checked, and amended the answer.

Comment: @Eran: I was still wrong, only *one* argument is auto-unboxed. I think I have it right now.

Comment: This answer looks correct. The [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25) official specification of the conditional operator is very complicated indeed.