# Why does javac not catch this ternary error?

Tags: javac, ternary

Clearly returning null for a boolean type is an error. Why doesn't javac catch this?

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object a = null;
        System.out.println(getThing(a));
    }

    private static boolean getThing(Object o) {
        return o == null ? null : Boolean.TRUE;
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tricky ternary operator in Java - autoboxing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8098953/tricky-ternary-operator-in-java-autoboxing)

Comment: This is also discussed here, but I didn't include autoboxing in my search so I didn't find it. [Java autoboxing and ternary operator madness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25417438/java-autoboxing-and-ternary-operator-madness)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The question

> *Clearly returning null for a boolean type is an error. Why doesn't javac catch this?*

Given that question, here's the relevant part of the code:

```
private static boolean getThing(Object o) {
    return o == null ? null : Boolean.TRUE;
}
```

That method includes a conditional expression
([JLS 15.25](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se18/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25))
where:

1. the first expression is `o == null`
2. the second expression is `null`
3. the third expression is `Boolean.TRUE`

#### Why it *compiles*

The reason `javac` allows it is:

- The conditional expression is classified as a reference conditional expression ([JLS 15.25.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se18/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25.3)) due to the second and third expressions
  "null" and "Boolean.TRUE", excerpted from [JLS 15.25](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se18/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25):

  > *If both the second and the third operand expressions are boolean expressions, the conditional expression is a boolean conditional expression.*
  >
  > *If both the second and the third operand expressions are numeric expressions, the conditional expression is a numeric conditional expression.*
  >
  > *Otherwise, the conditional expression is a reference conditional expression.*
- The entire conditional expression is classified as type `java.lang.Boolean`
- The conditional expression is of reference type `Boolean`, and the *method* return type – primitive "boolean" – can be [unboxed](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se18/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.8) from `Boolean`

The compiler kind of "allowing" a code path where "null" might be unboxed to "boolean" isn't all that different
from various other obvious programming errors.

For example, here's code that creates a new object, gives it a value of `null`, then tries
to invoke a method on that object.
This code compiles fine but, unsurprisingly, throws an exception at runtime:

```
Object o = null;
System.out.println(o.hashCode());

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException:
Cannot invoke "Object.hashCode()" because "o" is null
```

#### It compiles, but doesn't *run*

Though your code compiles, the following exception is thrown at runtime when `null` is unboxed to boolean:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException:
Cannot invoke "java.lang.Boolean.booleanValue()"
```

While the return value of the *statement* is `null` – a valid value for `Boolean` – unboxing to
a boolean primitive (to line up with the method return type) throws an exception. Unboxing tries to call `null.booleanValue()` which won't work.

You weren't asking, but – an easy fix would be
to change the return type of the method from primitive `boolean` to `Boolean`.
After doing that, your program compiles and runs, printing "null" (from `System.out.println(getThing(a))`.