# Why does this code give a null pointer Exception? I thought Character class could handle null being assigned?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, conditional-operator, boxing, autoboxing

```
public class Playground {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "blah";
    Character lclfs = s.contains("/") ? '/' : s.contains("\\") ? '\\' : null;
  }
}
```

What am I missing (using Java 1.8)?

[image]

Comment: Wow it does, I would say its because of autounboxing attempt

Comment: Not sure if it was the same and worth closing - they are similar -this was Character class. Definitely worth cross linking posts though. Cheers for all the help from everyone on this one. Was a real Java curveball for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because your code will try to unbox `null`. Using IntelliJ this will be shown directly as warning: "Unboxing of null may produce NullPointerException".

An alternative would be to do it like this:

```
String s = "blah";
Character lclfs = s.contains("/") ? Character.valueOf('/') : 
    s.contains("\\") ? Character.valueOf('\\') : null;
```

As @Antoniossss pointed out, this would also help:

```
String s = "blah";
Character lclfs = s.contains("/") ? Character.valueOf('/') : 
    s.contains("\\") ? (Character)'\\' : null;
```

Talking about warnings in IntelliJ, my above code is now saying: ”Unnecessary boxing 'Character.valueOf('\')'”. So probably you should try to refactor your code. Instead of using explicit `null`, you could introduce `java.util.Optional`:

```
Optional<Character> lclfs = s.contains("/") ? Optional.of('/') :
        s.contains("\\") ? Optional.of('\\') : Optional.empty();
```

Comment: I wonder why it is unboxed to char?

Comment: Thank you very much. That solved it. I thought Java would auto box. Very quirky! ;-)

Comment: Also, casting is enough